# Create a moving marker. Robot Operating System (ROS)

Tags: openstreetmap, ros, path-finding, robotics, planning

I'm trying to plan routes in ROS using OSM data and show the results in Rviz, using Python. Until now, my result is the following one:

Correct path computed by the algorithm shown in Rviz:
[image: Correct path computed by the algorithm shown in Rviz]

Now, what I need is to create a marker or something that follows this highlighted path (simulating a car moving on it).

The idea of my project is to simulate a car moving in the correct path and if the car goes to other street while moving because any reason (I will probably intentionally indicate by code that the car deviates), the algorithm is executed again to replan the route from the place the car is to the same final position.

Is there any way to do that simulation of the car moving in rviz?

I am very grateful for your contributions!

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own models using [Robot_model](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_model/Tutorials) Package and the set it's `base_frame` to the frame thats moving alongside your highlighted path.

also you can use any existing models(It may not look like the thing you want)
and if you don't know your moving frame you can use Axe inside Rviz to represent the location of the frame at any moment